# Error with stringWithContentsOfURL encoding with à è ò ù character

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I have a problem with this implementation:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:site] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&er];
```

the string site contains this character with the accent, for example : à è ò ù and every time a string contains one of this character for example this string:

```
http://...../Questa_é_la_mia_terra.html
```

the **"s"** string returns null, this happen also for other characters with the accent, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found this solution:

```
NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
NULL,
(CFStringRef)unencodedString,
NULL,
(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

and in this way seems work...from this website: http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/

Answer (score 0):

Encode `site` using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding` first.

See [Working with URLs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)